# How to fix a stack overflow error in Lisp

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have a code here that is trying to get the sum of all prime numbers below a given number. When I run it, I keep on getting a stack overflow error and nothing more and I can't seem to find where I went wrong.

```
(format t "Enter your number ~%")

;global variables
(defvar *number* (read))

(defvar *conditional-check* nil)

(defvar *prime* nil)



;sum-of-primes function 
(defun sum-of-primes (x)
    (defvar sum 0)
    (primeCheck x 2)
    (if (equal *prime* 'yes) 
        (progn
            (setf sum (+ sum x))
            (setf z (- x 1))
            (conditional z)
            (if (equal *conditional-check* 'yes) (sum-of-primes z) ()))
        (and (setf z (- x 1)) (sum-of-primes z)))
)


;conitional function
(defun conditional (z)
    (if (>= z 1) (setf *conditional-check* 'yes) (setf *conditional-check* 'no))
)


;prime number check
(defun primeCheck (*number* y)
    (if (and (>= *number* y) (not (= (mod *number* y) 0))) 
        (progn 
            (setf z (+ y 1))
            (primeCheck *number* z)
            (setf *prime* 'yes))
    (setf *prime* 'no))
)

;function call
(sum-of-primes *number*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum-of-primes` is missing some *base condition*, which ends recursive calling. That is main problem, but your code is very confusing and contains many useless global variables. You should avoid using global variables and use local variables (created by [let](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm) or function call). For this example, you don't need any global variables at all.

```
(defun sum-of-primes (num)
  (sum-of-primes-help 0 num))

(defun sum-of-primes-help (i num)
  (cond ((= i num) 0)
        ((primep i) (+ i (sum-of-primes-help (+ i 1) num)))
        (t (sum-of-primes-help (+ i 1) num))))
         
(defun primep (num)
    (primep-help 2 num))

(defun primep-help (i num)
  (cond ((= num 0) nil)
        ((= num 1) nil)
        ((= i num) t)
        ((= 0 (mod num i)) nil)
        (t (primep-help (+ i 1) num))))

(defun program ()
  (format t "Enter your number ~%")
  (format t "Sum of primes is: ~s" 
          (sum-of-primes (read))))
```

Then you just call `(program)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. Your code is neater and more readable. I just don't understand what this line of code does. `(t (sum-of-primes-help (+ i 1) num))`

Comment: And for this line `(cond ((= i num) 0)` I get that we are setting i to num but what is the 0 used for

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow means that the section of memory, called the stack reached its limit. To clarify, on the stack function calls are stored. Now, if the memory section where function calls are stored reaches its limit, that means that too many funcion calls occurred. This usually means infinite recursion. Imagine a function that only calls itself. Now, if you call that function, then that call is stored on the stack. However, the function calls itself and the second call is stored on the stack as well. And the second call is calling the function for a third time, which is stored on the stack and so on.

This bad use of recursion can be resolved by looking at the specific regions of the code where a function is called either by itself, or, to put it in broader terms, if a function is already on the stack, but it's being called again.

This is the understanding you need in order to figure out the solution to your current problem and to avoid similar problems in the future.